# C# / Access Getting Primary Keys from Access 2003

Tags: c#, ms-access, schema, oledb

I'm using OleDb to interact with an Access database, and I'm trying to find out how to get the primary keys of each table, but in such a way that they are associated with the tables. In other words, I don't just want a flat list of the primary key column names--I want to be able to determine which table they belong to.

Any idea how to do this? I've used the `GetSchema()` method to get a table of tables, but that table's information does not appear to include primary keys (or any other indexes, for that matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok--did a little outputting of column names and got a better understanding of how the schema tables are related.

To do this, pass the string "Indexes" to the `GetSchema()` method. Each record in the index table contains both the table name and whether or not the index is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is that for each FOREIGN KEY in the schema you want to discover the name of the referenced table. From a quick google it seems this may not be possible:

[Microsoft Connect: DbConnection.GetSchema: no ways to get foreign keys' columns](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=94352)

...which is strange because with ADO classic's (COM, not .NET) OpenSchema method you can.

Comment: I realize that the word "associated" can add confusion, but I'm indeed talking about primary keys in the tables in which they are actually primary keys. I wanted a listing of primary keys in a database, but not a "flat" listing where it's simply a list of those fields. I needed to know which table the primary key belonged to, as well--not just its name or other attributes. The "Indexes" schema table did the trick. Thanks for trying to answer, though.